# Term a 'sheet something' to prove you are a published journalist/writer?

Tags: journalism, terminology

Sometime back, I read somewhere that if you want to cover an event, the event organizer may ask to see a *'sheet something'*. I don't remember what this terminology or the phrase is.

The phrase basically denotes that you will print copies of your online work, put them in a bundle and show it to the organizer. If the organizer is satisfied with the content of your work, they may choose to give you a press pass for the event.

I'm looking to know/remember the term/phrase. It comes from olden times when a journalist used to cut articles out of a newspaper and keep them in a bundle in case if he needs to show his writing skills to an editor or somebody.

Does anybody know what this terminonolgy or phrase might be?

Comment: The term you're looking for is *tearsheet,* literally a sheet (page) torn out of a newspaper; the big ones were called *broadsheets.* Aside from that, you should know that definitions are off-topic for us but might be accepatble on English SE.

Comment: could you turn it into an answer please. Thank you.

Comment: Tearsheet is not right. I was a journalist for a while and still have my clippings. I don't have any tearsheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you're looking for is *tearsheet,* literally a sheet (page) torn out of a newspaper; the big ones like the *New York Times* were called *broadsheets.*

Comment: No, this is not right. Journalists keep clips or clippings of their work.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.poynter.org/2004/your-work-as-your-best-resume-tips-on-clips/22361/

Whether you're a working reporter looking for greener pastures or a college journalist hoping for that first job, your work will always be your best resumé.

In the newspaper world, your body of work is known as your "clips," short for "**clippings**."

> (noun) 1.1 An article cut from a newspaper or magazine
>   *"Posters, newspaper clippings, and magazine interviews littered his walls."*

<sup>[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clipping)</sup>

A young reporter interested in exploring new opportunities posed these questions about the process the other day: How many clips — and what kind — should I send?

An old article but still right.

Here's another one:

https://www.clippings.me/

> Add your best **clippings**, customize your page and then share your work with the world - without a single line of code. Thousands of journalists and writers trust us with their work, and building your website takes just minutes.

Comment: Like Lambie, I was a journalist for a while. I worked with one of the last hot-metal houses and some of the first full-colour presses used in Britain. I’ve never heard ’tearsheet’ closely enough associated with any press function that I even bothered to ask myself what it meant, let alone anyone else.

Clearly ‘tearsheet’ and ‘broadsheet’ share a root. I don’t think ‘broadsheet’ much more likely as a source than ‘tabloid’.

How did ‘on-line’ sneak in? Wouldn’t that stoke a ‘file’ or ‘portfolio’?

Check instead https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tear_sheet where content matters not…